# Warning: This class was probably produced by a broken compiler

Tags: android, jackson

I have added Jacson libs to my android project and now I am getting such warnings in console:

> warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. (This class
>   was probably produced by a broken compiler.)

I've tried to recompile libs, but it didn't help. Warnings are gone when I remove these libs from project. Everything is working fine on the device, but this annoys me ;)

Do you know any solution? I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Which version is this? All Jackson versions are compiled with standard Sun JDK javac (earlier v1.5, newer ones with 1.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to recompile libs, but it
>   didn't help.

Meaning you added the Jackson source to your Android project? Usually that will point out the places where it finds problems or otherwise clears up this issue.

Comment: Tried that and Eclipse is not pointing out places with a problem. Previously I have compiled whole project using ant and have added libs I need to my project. Now I have added whole source tree to workspace and referenced it from my project - still the same...

Comment: just be aware that Jackson is LGPL so you probably don't want to link your source directly with their source unless you want to pollute it. A better option would be to contact their directly and see if they know what the issue is.

Comment: Jackson is dual-licensed with either LGPL or ASL (there are two jars, each with license name included)